# Struggling with promise implementation

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I have two functions. The first is an `animationFunction()` that runs for a certain amount of time. The second is a `parentFunction()` that needs a function called `dispatch()` to be run after the `animationFunction()` has stopped looping. `dispatch()` can only be called from the parent function:

```
const animationFunction = (args) => {
  const duration = 1000;

  //init animation function stuff...

  //draw loop
  const loop = drawLoop(({ time }) => {
    if (time > duration) {
      loop.stop();
    }
  });
};

const parentFunction = () => {
  animationFunction(args);
  //dispatch be run after animationFunction is done looping
  dispatch(); 
}
```

I think `animationFunction()` can be thought of as asynchronous, because it requires a certain amount of time to loop before the program can proceed. I figured out a way using callbacks to get `dispatch()` to run in the parent function after `animationFunction()` is done looping, but I'm confused on how to use a promise-based implementation. Here's my callback solution:

```
const animationFunction = (args, callback) => {
  const duration = 1000;

  //init animation function stuff...

  //draw loop
  const loop = drawLoop(({ time }) => {
    if (time > duration) {
      loop.stop();
      callback();
    }
  });
};

const parentFunction = () => {
  animationFunction(args, () => {
    //dispatch should be run after animationFunction is done looping
    dispatch();
  }); 
}
```

I'm confused about the `Promise`-based solution. I tried doing this:

```
const animationFunction = (args) => {
  const duration = 1000;

  //init animation function stuff...

  //draw loop
  const loop = drawLoop(({ time }) => {
    if (time > duration) {
      loop.stop();
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve();
      });
    }
  });
};

const parentFunction = () => {
  animationFunction(args).then(() => {
    dispatch();
  });
}
```

But this didn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `animationFunction` isn't returning a promise, in fact it isn't returning anything

Comment: You should create the Promise at the start of your function so that a) it wraps all of your async code and b) you can chain by using .then, you can't return it out from your drawLoop callback. But the call to resolve is in the right place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning the promise not to `animationFunction`'s caller but to the `drawLoop` scope where it's probably not dealt with (it's hard to tell from your example since most of the code is missing).

Instead, return a promise from `animationFunction` and `resolve` it when the timer is up. Here's a minimal, reproducible example:

```js
const animationFunction = () => {
  const duration = 10;
  let ticks = 0;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    (function update() {
      console.log(ticks++);

      if (ticks >= duration) {
        return resolve("some optional data");
      }

      requestAnimationFrame(update);
    })();
  });
};

animationFunction().then(data => {
  console.log("dispatched: " + data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are returning the Promise in the callback function of drawloop instead of animationFunction.

It should do the trick:

```js
const animationFunction = (args) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const duration = 1000;

    //init animation function stuff...

    //draw loop
    const loop = drawLoop(({ time }) => {
      if (time > duration) {
        loop.stop();
        resolve();
      }
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost there, this will work:

```
const animationFunction = (args) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const duration = 1000;

  //init animation function stuff...

  //draw loop
  const loop = drawLoop(({ time }) => {
    if (time > duration) {
      loop.stop();
      resolve();
    }
  });
 });
};

const parentFunction = () => {
  animationFunction(args).then(() => {
    dispatch();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You return that promise from drawLoop’s callback, that does not make `animationFunction` return promise. Fix like below:

```
const animationFunction = (args) => {
  const duration = 1000;

  //init animation function stuff...

  let done;
  const promise = new Promise((resolve) => { done = resolve });

  //draw loop
  const loop = drawLoop(({ time }) => {
    if (time > duration) {
      loop.stop();
      done();
    }
  });

  return promise;
};
```